# can't pass image from tableViewCell to detailVC through segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I try to pass my image from the tableViewCell to the detailVC if the cell get tapped, but the imageView on the detailVC is empty where normally the image from the cell should be...
My current code works for textLabels as an example, but somehow not for the image

Comment: may be `jobs[indexPath.row].jobImage` is nil ?

Comment: can it be possible although it get's shown without problems in the tableViewCell?? I also tried it but then I get all the time an error saying Thread1: Unexpectedly found nil....

Comment: that means it's nil , verify all model items have no-nil job image

Comment: sorry, I may be to dumb for this but I used "!" "?" "?? nil" in any combination I could probably think off to see if it works but I didn't got it fixed... I updated my question with the code from the job.swift file... So I don't really understand why I can upload it to firebase and stuff - get it shown on the tableView - but can't pass it to the detailVC... you really would do me a favor if you could help me with this @Sh_Khan

Comment: @J.Doe I hope my answer helped. How are you populating your jobs array, I believe there could be a problem in there, otherwise, if you are open to tweaking your implementation, my proposed solution should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Opinionated Solution***

The code here suggests that you are using Firebase. Retrieving images from Firebase requires:

1. A reference to the download URL of the image ( as you have)
2. An extra call to actually download the image from your storage container (not sure if you are doing this in other parts of your code not shared)

Regardless, you should not send the actual image to the detailVC in my opinion. Try instead to send the download URL and attempt to download the image in detailVC, or to pull it from cache if you are caching. The reason for this is, imagine if the user clicks on a cell when the image has not finished downloading (he/she may know from other cell details that this is the cell of interest), would you wait for the image to download before displaying the detailVC? That seems contrary to what a user would expect. So it may just be better to handle the downloadURL instead of the whole image.

Just throwing this out there in case: Make sure that when you finish downloading your image you call the main thread to update the UIImage. Read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker) for reference.

Comment: Hey, first of all I'm super sorry for the late answer... but however I tried now different ways and ended up to following your idea with the updated code on detailVC, but now the imageView still keeps empty... did I made anything wrong or did I understood something wrong? I hope you can still help me although I let you wait for so many days...

Comment: Hey, I am glad you got it to work, what was the issue with the new implementation you were having? I took a look at your comment yesterday and was planning to write you today

Comment: There was a missing "?" behind the String for downloadURL in the JobDetail structure Model... well sometimes it's one of the small things haha

Comment: Ah ok. So usually things that come down from the server will be marked as [Optional](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) (the question mark after a variable indicates that). Optionals make sure that a variable can never be set to "null" and thus crash your program. So in data that comes from the server, you cannot guarantee that all the fields have been set on a particular object, so you would mark them as optional with a "?"